# DB not updating with django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to workaround a small project, new to django.

Here are my urls:

```
url(r'^createreceivable/$',views.createreceivables,name = 'createreceivable'),
```

My views.py

```
@login_required
def createreceivables(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rec_form = Receivablesforms(data=request.POST)
        if rec_form.is_valid():
            rec_form.save()
            return render(request,'account/dashboard.html')
    else:
        rec_form = Receivablesforms()

    return render(request,'account/addreceivable.html',{'rec_form':rec_form})
```

My model.py

```
class Receivables(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    receivable_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    receivable_address = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_email = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_telephone = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_VAT = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_Service_Tax = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
    receivable_PAN = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class Receivablesforms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Receivables
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Everything works perfect, except that data is not saved in DB. Please guide.

```
instance=request.user is not working
```

Template is

```
<form action="." method="post">
{{ rec_form }}
{% csrf_token %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Save Changes"</p>
</form>
```

Comment: I am using Mysql as DB.

Comment: What's your code for using the form?

Comment: @ShangWang updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you excluded the user, you need to get it back somehow, otherwise your `rec_form.save()` would have exception because your model needs `user` field to be filled.

The trick is to use `save(commit=False)`. It will create an object in memory but it won't save it. You just have to assign `user` to the in-memory object and save it again:

```
if rec_form.is_valid():
    new_rec = rec_form.save(commit=False)
    new_rec.user = request.user
    new_rec.save()
```

Check django doc about [`commit=False` in `save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).